# Asp.net membership Provider gives : Authentication Bypass Using SQL Injection in appscan

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I've got an "appscan" report , and one of the issues was the following  :

Entity : txtPassword (Parameter)
Risk : It may be possible to bypass the web application's authentication mechanism
Causes :Sanitation of hazardous characters was not performed correctly on user input
Fix :Review possible solutions for hazardous character injection
Difference :

```
        Cookie removed from request: z5jsbpphcwehckb4ubvhltbv

        Parameter:manipulated from: testagent TO 4ppSc4n

        Parameter:manipulated from: testagent TO 4ppSc4n

        Parameter:manipulated from: testagent TO A%27+OR+%277659%27%3D%277659

        Parameter:manipulated from: testagent TO s3ct3amy

        Reasoning: The test result seems to indicate a vulnerability
        because when four types of request were sent - a valid login, an
        invalid login, an SQL attack, and another invalid login - the
        responses to the two invalid logins were the same, while the
        response to the SQL attack seems similar the response to the 
        valid login.
```

Where "testagent" is acorrect password value for the account and the other values are not .

however , in the code behind I'm using asp.net membership provider as the following :

```
  bool isValid = Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
if (user.isValid )                    
{
 Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
}
else
{
    ltrMessage="In Valid Login";
}
```

"txtUsername" and "txtPassword" are "asp:TextBox" controls.

how to solve this issue .

Comment: Are you using a custom-made `MembershipProvider` implementation? Please show some of its relevant code, in that case.

Comment: yes I am , using Aspnet_regsql.exe to register related tables into the DB , in me web.config , I used (machineKey and "<add connectionStringName="ABCRCS" enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Encrypted" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />") , and I modified my code :) .

Comment: Then, no you are **not** using a **custom-made** implementation. You are using one from the framework. You shouldn't get that warning, I believe. This needs more debugging. Look at what SQL queries are sent to your SQL server and analyze them.

Comment: I'll check thank alot .